# Linux kernel compiling commands

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, linux-kernel

I'm trying to make a mini operating system (using the linux kernel). I'm planning on it being for x86 and I'm trying to make it so that it not only runs on qemu but also on a real device. What are the exact commands that I would need to put into terminal to do this?

Comment: If you need to ask this question, you're not ready to make your own OS.

Comment: You should consider reading [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/index.html). It is guide for compiling and installing all necessary components for custom Linux system.

Comment: @hluk, you'd re-post your comment as an answer.

Comment: However, It's closed, and it's overly stupid, narrow-m***d ..etc ..etc. and authoritatively rhetorical (i.e. stupid question). But I'dont think so + LFS is not stupid it's the best system to probe! -that's it.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDxavve6Smk

Comment: This article series may help someone (http://www.linux.org/threads/%EF%BB%BFthe-linux-kernel-introduction.4203/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Complete Documentation for compiling Linux Kernels can be found here
http://openprobe.blogspot.in/2010/12/build-and-compile-your-own-linux-kernel.html